# Incompatible types?

Tags: java

I am trying to delete the address book entry where the input is name, but I get 
    java:148 error: incompatible types
             return fileToDelete.delete();

```
required: AddressBookEntry
found:    boolean
```

1 error

The code in question is:

```
    public class AddressBookDelegateImpl implements AddressBookDelegate {

    private File userHomeDir;

    private File addressBookDirectory;
    private String replaceSpacesWithUnderScores( String string ) {
        return string.replaceAll( " ", "_" ).toLowerCase();
    }

    public AddressBookEntry deleteAddressBookEntry( String name )
                              throws AddressBookDelegateException {

        try{
            String dname = replaceSpacesWithUnderScores( name );
            File fileToDelete = new File( addressBookDirectory, dname );
            return fileToDelete.delete() ;
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            throw new AddressBookDelegateException("Could not find the file", e);
        }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method returns and `AddressBookEntry` in it's declaration:

```
public AddressBookEntry deleteAddressBookEntry( String name )
```

while the return statement says:

```
 return fileToDelete.delete() ;
```

You might want to consider declaring `AddressBookEntry` return type as `boolean` like this:

```
public boolean deleteAddressBookEntry( String name )
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks Done that infact I changed the interface consequently.I also had a DeleteAction class which had:

Comment: Yeah Thanks Done that infact I changed the interface consequently.I also had a DeleteAction class which had:                            try {
           AddressBookEntry addressBookEntry =
                    addressBookDelegate.deleteAddressBookEntry( name );

Comment: Now It compiles. The application allows the user to add a new address, view details of one entry by asking the user to input the name, view all the names in the address book. Now we are incorporating a delete function which asks the user to input the name to delete. I then retrieves the attributes of that name as addressbookentry and now am supposed to delete this entry.When I run with the suggested changes I get a null pointer exception!

Comment: Ok I have modified the AddressBookGuiimpl class as:

Comment: String name = readInput();
DeleteAddressActionArgument deleteAddressActionArgument =new DeleteAddressActionArgument( name );
ActionResult actionResult =controller.execute( deleteAddressActionArgument );
DeleteAddressActionResult deleteAddressActionResult= ( DeleteAddressActionResult )actionResult;
AddressBookEntry addressBookEntry =deleteAddressActionResult.getAddressBookEntry();
removeAddressBookEntry( addressBookEntry );
}

Comment: private void removeAddressBookEntry(AddressBookEntry addressBookEntry ) {
if ( addressBookEntry != null ) {
File deleted=new File(addressBookEntry);
deleted.delete();
'}
else {
print( "Could not find entry" );
}
}'

Comment: error:no suitable constructor found for File(AddressBookEntry) File deleted=new File(addressBookEntry);constructor File.File(URI) is not applicable (actual argument AddressBookEntry cannot be converted to URI by method invocation conversion)

Comment: constructor File.File(File,String) is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)constructor File.File(String,String) is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor File.File(String) is not applicable(actual argument AddressBookEntry cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)constructor File.File(String,File) is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)constructor File.File(String,int) is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)1 error

Answer (score 0):

`File.delete()` return a boolean...

Answer (score 0):

Well the error already describes it quite well. The method *delete* returns a boolean if the delete was successful or not. So you should check that return value if its true and then return the AddressBookEntry which you've deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the return type of the method is defined in the method declaration.
So in your example, you have:

```
   public AddressBookEntry deleteAddressBookEntry( String name )throws AddressBookDelegateException {

       try{
           String dname = replaceSpacesWithUnderScores( name );
           File fileToDelete = new File( addressBookDirectory, dname );
           return fileToDelete.delete() ; //this returns a boolean
       } catch(NullPointerException e) {
          throw new AddressBookDelegateException("Could not find the file", e);
       }
   }
```

So if you would prefer not to change your return method, which is probably what you want to do, you should try this code instead:

```
   public boolean deleteAddressBookEntry( String name )throws AddressBookDelegateException {

       try{
           String dname = replaceSpacesWithUnderScores( name );
           File fileToDelete = new File( addressBookDirectory, dname );
           return fileToDelete.delete() ; //this returns a boolean
       } catch(NullPointerException e) {
          throw new AddressBookDelegateException("Could not find the file", e);
       }
   }
```

Which will return the result of the `fileToDelete.delete()` method.

Answer (score 0):

please modified your method deleteAddressBookEntry as per below:

```
public Boolean deleteAddressBookEntry(String name)
                throws AddressBookDelegateException {
            try {
                String dname = replaceSpacesWithUnderScores(name);
                File fileToDelete = new File(addressBookDirectory, dname);
                if(fileToDelete.exists())
                    return fileToDelete.delete();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                throw new AddressBookDelegateException("Could not find the file", e);
            }
            return false;
        }
```